# Meteor: Mongo sort on subkey

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In Meteor's ["Parties" example](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/parties/model.js), there is a Party model which is represented by a document of the following schema:

```
Each party is represented by a document in the Parties collection:
  owner: user id
  x, y: Number (screen coordinates in the interval [0, 1])
  title, description: String
  public: Boolean
  invited: Array of user id's that are invited (only if !public)
  rsvps: Array of objects like {user: userId, rsvp: "yes"} (or "no"/"maybe")
```

I would like to find all Parties, and sort by the "rsvps" based on a specific user. For example, something like this:

```
Meteor.find({sort: {rsvps: {user: 'myself', rsvp: 'yes'}}})
```

But of course, this does not work, as it does not follow the [sort specifier syntax](http://docs.meteor.com/#find). Also, there is a note in the same docs that say Minimongo (the local Mongo implementation on the client) does not support sorting on subkeys. However, I don't think the issue is simply sorting on subkeys, as I need to find a specific subkey and *then* sort on a different sibling subkey (whether they are attending or not, the `rsvps.rsvp` subkey).

Are there any ways, or workarounds, achieve the sorted collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimongo sort file contains this comment :

```
// XXX sort does not yet support subkeys ('a.b') .. fix that!
```

So sadly it isn't supported at the moment. Although I have this pull request from which you can take the needed parts to implement this feature.

Check it out here :

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/443

Lander Van Breda

Comment: As of Meteor 0.5.3, your commit has been released!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to get the data out of the Cursor with '.fetch()' and then use something like underscore.js's _.sortBy to sort the resulting Array.

The resulting custom sorted array can then be passed on to handlebars and will retain its reactive features as well in Meteor.